# Google Place Api, Find Place From Text not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-places-api

I've been trying to use the google place api to get the shops inside a specified range from my coordinates and street adress as parameter, but not lucky.
Would be possible to someone tell me what if I may be sending the request with the wrong parameters?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=wickham%20street&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,opening_hours,rating&locationbias=circle:500@-27.4554492,153.0334623&key=[APIKEY]
```

Thank you